Exception while upgrading Spring and Camel
I have a multi-module application that currently running with java 11,Spring version 4.3.7.RELEASE and Camel version 2.18.4. Now I upgraded to Java 17, Spring 5.5.10 and Camel 3.20.0 Facing below issue
org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for:  of type: org.apache.camel.ErrorHandlerFactory
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>

                
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.21</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.21</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.21</version>
            </dependency>

            
            <!-- Testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.10</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>5.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>  <!--Only necessary for surefire to run spock tests during the maven build -->
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Maven -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                 <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                 <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Enabling Log4j2 slf4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Camel components -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-support</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-xml</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-tracing</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-integration</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                       <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Integration -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.20</version>
            </dependency>


did you resolve this? can we resolve by including the camel-core-model?
